# Google Sheets' regular expression calculation

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Can I compute the numeral part of a string then put it back in the string using Google Sheets?

[image: 0]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13zl7uUq8EtbdLDVFrLKfD7XOQ4feqd9Xrm2F4NX6L54/edit

Comment: Would you please provide an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: Given the string in cell C1 the output in C2 should be 21 x ecobulb Reflector; 18 x onsemi CFL

Comment: I've edited your question to show the expected outcome that you described. Please correct this if it is wrong. Personally, I do not understand how you get C2 from C1. Would you please explain the logic for how you arrive at the value in cell C2.

Comment: In cell c1 if with reference to cells a1 and a2 will search a match within c1 if found a match like for example a2=reflector is match then if will convert the numerical part then multiply it by the equivalent of A2-reflector which is in b2=3 that is why the result is 21

Comment: Why are the values in Column B "prices" when they are only used as multipliers for quantity?

Comment: I just put those values of cfl and reflectors in column B as reference. You can put cfl in a1 and b1 for reflectors a2 and b2 with their values

Comment: You're right i gave a wrong format.

Comment: Here is the link to the spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13zl7uUq8EtbdLDVFrLKfD7XOQ4feqd9Xrm2F4NX6L54

Comment: Two things: 1) in your example, you reference only two "Types", and the "Reference value" contains only two types. In practice, could there be more than two Types, and could the "Reference value" contain more than two Types? 2) You said "Can I compute... " Are you expecting to do this with a built-in function, custom function, or a script?

Comment: 1) Yes, in reality there are several types of lights. 2) Custom formula in google sheet. Because I'm using google sheets not excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(";", 1, 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(C1, ";")), A1), 
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(C1, ";"))&" @ $"&A2&" = "&
 REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(C1, ";")), "\d+")*A2, 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(C1, ";")), B1), 
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(C1, ";"))&" @ $"&B2&" = "&
 REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(C1, ";")), "\d+")*B2, ))))
```

[image: 0]